# Syscall hooking in kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to hook an open syscall using a lkm and IOCTL in linux kernel 5.19. The code is actually working, i can see all the debug print using dmesg, but when i run a test program that implements an open, i cannot see the print of my hook any suggestion?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>                 //kmalloc()
#include <linux/uaccess.h>              //copy_to/from_user()
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <asm/special_insns.h>
 
#define WR_VALUE _IOW('a','a',int32_t*)
#define RD_VALUE _IOR('a','b',int32_t*)
#define IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE 0x00000001
#define IOCTL_FIX_TABLE 0x00000004
 
int32_t value = 0;
 
dev_t dev = 0;
static struct class *dev_class;
static struct cdev etx_cdev;

/*
** Function Prototypes
*/
static int      __init etx_driver_init(void);
static void     __exit etx_driver_exit(void);
static int      etx_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static int      etx_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static ssize_t  etx_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len,loff_t * off);
static ssize_t  etx_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t len, loff_t * off);
static long     etx_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);

unsigned long *sys_call_table = (unsigned long*)0xffffffffa70004c0; //hard coded address of sys_call_table from /boot/System.map

asmlinkage int (*real_open)(const char* __user, int, int);
asmlinkage int (*real_openat)(int, const char*, int, umode_t);
asmlinkage int (*real_openat_)(const struct pt_regs *);
asmlinkage int (*real_openat2)(int, const char*, struct open_how*, size_t);

asmlinkage int custom_open(const char* __user file_name, int flags, int mode){
        pr_info("interceptor: open(\"%s\", %X, %X)\n", file_name,flags,mode);
    //return open(file_name,flags,mode);
        return (*real_open)(file_name, flags, mode);
}

asmlinkage long custom_openat_(const struct pt_regs *regs){
   pr_info(KERN_INFO "%s: interceptor: openat_\n", __func__);
   return real_openat_(regs);
}

asmlinkage long custom_openat(int dirfd, const char __user* pathname, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
   pr_info(KERN_INFO "%s: interceptor: openat\n", __func__);
   return real_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags, mode);
}

asmlinkage long custom_openat2(int dirfd, const char __user* pathname, struct open_how *how, size_t size)
{
   pr_info(KERN_INFO "%s: interceptor: openat\n", __func__);
   return real_openat2(dirfd, pathname, how, size);
}

static struct file_operations fops =
{ 
        .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
        .read           = etx_read,
        .write          = etx_write,
        .open           = etx_open,
        .unlocked_ioctl = etx_ioctl,
        .release        = etx_release,
};

int make_rw(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
        //printk(_PAGE_RW, pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW);
    if(pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW) //bitwise and -> if the page is 
        pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW; //bitwise or -> put the result inside pte->pte in the pte_t struct
    return 0;
}

//Make the page write protected
int make_ro(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

static int etx_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        pr_info("Device File Opened...!!!\n");
        return 0;
}

static int etx_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        pr_info("Device File Closed...!!!\n");
        return 0;
}

static ssize_t etx_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
        pr_info("Read Function\n");
        return 0;
}

static ssize_t etx_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
        pr_info("Write function\n");
        return len;
}

static inline void _write_cr0(unsigned long val)
{
    asm volatile("mov %0,%%cr0" : "+r"(val) : : "memory");
}

static inline void _write_cr4(unsigned long val)
{
    asm volatile("mov %0,%%cr4" : "+r"(val) : : "memory");
}

static inline void wp_disable(void)
{
    _write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
}

static inline void wp_enable(void)
{
    _write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);
}

static long etx_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
         switch(cmd) {
                case WR_VALUE:
                        if( copy_from_user(&value ,(int32_t*) arg, sizeof(value)) )
                        {
                                pr_err("Data Write : Err!\n");
                        }
                        pr_info("Value = %d\n", value);
                        break;
                case RD_VALUE:
                        if( copy_to_user((int32_t*) arg, &value, sizeof(value)) )
                        {
                                pr_err("Data Read : Err!\n");
                        }
                        break;
                case IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE:
                        //disable_write_protection();
                        //pr_info("address of real open before WP edit: %p",sys_call_table[__NR_open]);

                        wp_disable();
                        pr_info("syscalltable edited\n");
                        
                        real_open = (void*)(sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
                        real_openat = (void*)(sys_call_table[__NR_openat]);
                        real_openat2 = (void*)(sys_call_table[__NR_openat2]);
                        pr_info("address of real open: %p", *real_open);
                        pr_info("address of real openat: %p", *real_openat_);
                        pr_info("address of real openat: %p", *real_openat2);
                        pr_info("address of custom open: %p", custom_open);
                        pr_info("address of custom openat: %p", custom_openat_);
                        pr_info("address of custom openat2: %p", custom_openat2);
                        sys_call_table[__NR_open] = custom_open;
                        sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = custom_openat_;
                        sys_call_table[__NR_openat2] = custom_openat2;
                        pr_info("syscalltable open address edited\n");
                        pr_info("new address of open is: %p\n", sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
                        pr_info("new address of openat is: %p\n", sys_call_table[__NR_openat]);
                        pr_info("new address of openat2 is: %p\n", sys_call_table[__NR_openat2]);
                        wp_enable();
                        pr_info("syscalltable restored\n");
                        //enable_write_protection();
                        break;
                case IOCTL_FIX_TABLE:
                        //disable_write_protection();
                        wp_disable();
                        sys_call_table[__NR_open] = real_open;
                        sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = real_openat_;
                        sys_call_table[__NR_openat2] = real_openat2;
                        wp_enable();
                        //enable_write_protection();
                        break;
                default:
                        pr_info("Default\n");
                        break;
        }
        return 0;
}
 
static int __init etx_driver_init(void)
{
        /*Allocating Major number*/
        if((alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, "etx_Dev")) <0){
                pr_err("Cannot allocate major number\n");
                return -1;
        }
        pr_info("Major = %d Minor = %d \n", MAJOR(dev), MINOR(dev));
 
        /*Creating cdev structure*/
        cdev_init(&etx_cdev,&fops);
 
        /*Adding character device to the system*/
        if((cdev_add(&etx_cdev,dev,1)) < 0){
            pr_err("Cannot add the device to the system\n");
            goto r_class;
        }
 
        /*Creating struct class*/
        if(IS_ERR(dev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,"etx_class"))){
            pr_err("Cannot create the struct class\n");
            goto r_class;
        }
 
        /*Creating device*/
        if(IS_ERR(device_create(dev_class,NULL,dev,NULL,"etx_device"))){
            pr_err("Cannot create the Device 1\n");
            goto r_device;
        }
        pr_info("Device Driver Insert...Done!!!\n");
        return 0;
 
r_device:
        class_destroy(dev_class);
r_class:
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev,1);
        return -1;
}

static void __exit etx_driver_exit(void)
{
        device_destroy(dev_class,dev);
        class_destroy(dev_class);
        cdev_del(&etx_cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        pr_info("Device Driver Remove...Done!!!\n");
}
 
module_init(etx_driver_init);
module_exit(etx_driver_exit);
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("1.5");
```

I'm using `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call` in order to get the addres of the syscall table and the following is the test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
 
#define WR_VALUE _IOW('a','a',int32_t*)
#define RD_VALUE _IOR('a','b',int32_t*)
#define IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE 0x00000001
#define IOCTL_FIX_TABLE 0x00000004
 
int main()
{
        int fd;
        int fptr;
        int32_t value, number;
 
        printf("\nOpening Driver\n");
        fd = open("/dev/etx_device", O_RDWR);
        if(fd < 0) {
                printf("Cannot open device file...\n");
                return 0;
        }
 
        printf("Enter the Value to send\n");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        printf("Writing Value to Driver\n");
        ioctl(fd, WR_VALUE, (int32_t*) &number); 
 
        printf("Reading Value from Driver\n");
        ioctl(fd, RD_VALUE, (int32_t*) &value);
        printf("Value is %d\n", value);
        
        printf("Patching Syscall table\n");
        ioctl(fd, IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE, NULL);
        fptr = open("/home/osboxes/test.txt", O_RDONLY);
        printf("fptr: %d\n",fptr);

        printf("Fixing Syscall table\n");
        ioctl(fd, IOCTL_FIX_TABLE, NULL);

        printf("Closing Driver\n");
        close(fd);
}
```

Comment: You will need to consider the effect of `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER`, but modules really have no business messing around with the system call table. (Actually, there are up to three system call tables for x64 for compatibility with ia32 and x32.)

Comment: so basically i should modify each of this 3 sys_call_table? or maybe i should change approach